# Force TYPO3 to cache non-cached pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am facing a TYPO3 performance problem.
When I clear the cache of my website, the website waits for a user to visit pages again to cache the website. This seems to be a time consuming task and obviously this affects the performance.

So I would like to create a new extension or scheduler task which will check on a regular interval for pages which are not cached, and I want to force the pages to get cached. 
So my question is: how is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [EXT:crawler](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/crawler), which allow you to index your website, including custom URLs with extnesion's parameters.

Current TER version is [not compatible](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/55106) with TYPO3 6.2 yet, but [latest git version](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-crawler/repository) is, so you can take it.

Comment: Thanks fro your feedback viktor. But my question is, will the extension  EXT:crawler check for un-cached pages and then it force the pages to get cached again ?

Comment: Also how I would know that , whether a page is cached or not ?

Comment: It doesn't check for uncached pages. It simply crawls your website, like a normal FE user would do, and then TYPO3 core cares about page's cache. Sure, if you have disabled caching by no_cache or any other configuartion option, page will not be cached by core.